# Trying to use HtmlUnit to navigate through website

Tags: java, html, parsing, web-scraping, htmlunit

I am trying to use HtmlUnit to login to the dating website, http://www.pof.com, and navigate through its pages. I am unable to successfully do the first step (logging in). I am a beginner so check out my code below. Could it be that the website is restricting the bot itself?

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlForm;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTextInput;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlSubmitInput;

public class DataWebBot {


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

   // navigate & fetch HTML        
   final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

   //Get first page
   final HtmlPage pofLoginPage = webClient.getPage("http://www.pof.com");

   //Get the login form and find the user/password fields and submit button. 
   final HtmlForm loginForm = pofLoginPage.getFormByName("frmLogin");
   final HtmlTextInput usernameField = loginForm.getInputByName("username");
   final HtmlTextInput passwordField = loginForm.getInputByName("password");
   final HtmlSubmitInput loginButton = loginForm.getInputByName("submitbutton");

   //Set value of text field, login and get the second page
   usernameField.setValueAttribute("myUsername");
   passwordField.setValueAttribute("myPassword");

   webClient.getCookieManager().getCookies();

   System.out.println("Complete");
  }
}
```

And I am getting these errors:

```
Feb 26, 2014 4:59:38 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.ActiveXObject jsConstructor
WARNING: Automation server can't create object for 'ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash.7'.
Feb 26, 2014 4:59:38 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.StrictErrorReporter runtimeError
SEVERE: runtimeError: message=[Automation server can't create object for 'ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash.7'.] sourceName=[http://www.pof.com/javascript/versioned/pofcommon.min.1386808612.js] line=[5] lineSource=[null] lineOffset=[0]
Feb 26, 2014 4:59:38 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.ActiveXObject jsConstructor
WARNING: Automation server can't create object for 'ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash.6'.
Feb 26, 2014 4:59:38 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.StrictErrorReporter runtimeError
SEVERE: runtimeError: message=[Automation server can't create object for 'ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash.6'.] sourceName=[http://www.pof.com/javascript/versioned/pofcommon.min.1386808612.js] line=[5] lineSource=[null] lineOffset=[0]
Feb 26, 2014 4:59:38 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.ActiveXObject jsConstructor
WARNING: Automation server can't create object for 'ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash'.
Feb 26, 2014 4:59:38 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.StrictErrorReporter runtimeError
SEVERE: runtimeError: message=[Automation server can't create object for 'ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash'.] sourceName=[http://www.pof.com/javascript/versioned/pofcommon.min.1386808612.js] line=[5] lineSource=[null] lineOffset=[0]
Feb 26, 2014 4:59:38 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.ActiveXObject jsConstructor
WARNING: Automation server can't create object for 'ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash'.
Feb 26, 2014 4:59:38 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.StrictErrorReporter runtimeError
SEVERE: runtimeError: message=[Automation server can't create object for 'ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash'.] sourceName=[http://www.pof.com/javascript/versioned/pofcommon.min.1386808612.js] line=[5] lineSource=[null] lineOffset=[0]
Feb 26, 2014 4:59:39 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
Feb 26, 2014 4:59:40 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'http://www.pof.com/css/versioned/main.min.1392865551.css' [1:769] Error in expression. (Invalid token "}". Was expecting one of: <S>, <NUMBER>, "inherit", <IDENT>, <STRING>, <PLUS>, <HASH>, <EMS>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <PERCENTAGE>, <DIMENSION>, <URI>, <FUNCTION>, "-".)
Feb 26, 2014 4:59:40 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'http://www.pof.com/css/versioned/main.min.1392865551.css' [1:8694] Error in style rule. (Invalid token "*". Was expecting one of: <EOF>, <S>, <IDENT>, "}", ";".)
Feb 26, 2014 4:59:40 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: 'http://www.pof.com/css/versioned/main.min.1392865551.css' [1:8694] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
Feb 26, 2014 4:59:40 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'http://www.pof.com/css/versioned/main.min.1392865551.css' [1:8899] Error in style rule. (Invalid token "*". Was expecting one of: <EOF>, <S>, <IDENT>, "}", ";".)
Feb 26, 2014 4:59:40 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: 'http://www.pof.com/css/versioned/main.min.1392865551.css' [1:8899] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
Feb 26, 2014 4:59:40 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'http://www.pof.com/css/versioned/main.min.1392865551.css' [1:9105] Error in style rule. (Invalid token "*". Was expecting one of: <EOF>, <S>, <IDENT>, "}", ";".)
Feb 26, 2014 4:59:40 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: 'http://www.pof.com/css/versioned/main.min.1392865551.css' [1:9105] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
Feb 26, 2014 4:59:40 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'http://www.pof.com/css/versioned/main.min.1392865551.css' [1:9310] Error in style rule. (Invalid token "*". Was expecting one of: <EOF>, <S>, <IDENT>, "}", ";".)
Feb 26, 2014 4:59:40 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: 'http://www.pof.com/css/versioned/main.min.1392865551.css' [1:9310] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
Feb 26, 2014 4:59:40 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'http://www.pof.com/css/versioned/main.min.1392865551.css' [1:9544] Error in style rule. (Invalid token "*". Was expecting one of: <EOF>, <S>, <IDENT>, "}", ";".)
Feb 26, 2014 4:59:40 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: 'http://www.pof.com/css/versioned/main.min.1392865551.css' [1:9544] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
Feb 26, 2014 4:59:40 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'http://www.pof.com/css/versioned/main.min.1392865551.css' [1:12238] Error in style rule. (Invalid token ":". Was expecting one of: <EOF>, <S>, <NUMBER>, "inherit", <IDENT>, <STRING>, <PLUS>, <COMMA>, <HASH>, <IMPORTANT_SYM>, <EMS>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <PERCENTAGE>, <DIMENSION>, <URI>, <FUNCTION>, "}", ";", "/", "-".)
Feb 26, 2014 4:59:40 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: 'http://www.pof.com/css/versioned/main.min.1392865551.css' [1:12238] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
Feb 26, 2014 4:59:40 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'http://www.pof.com/css/versioned/main.min.1392865551.css' [1:16850] Error in style rule. (Invalid token "*". Was expecting one of: <EOF>, <S>, <IDENT>, "}", ";".)
Feb 26, 2014 4:59:40 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: 'http://www.pof.com/css/versioned/main.min.1392865551.css' [1:16850] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
Feb 26, 2014 4:59:40 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'http://www.pof.com/css/versioned/main.min.1392865551.css' [1:19023] Error in style rule. (Invalid token ":". Was expecting one of: <EOF>, <S>, <NUMBER>, "inherit", <IDENT>, <STRING>, <PLUS>, <COMMA>, <HASH>, <IMPORTANT_SYM>, <EMS>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <PERCENTAGE>, <DIMENSION>, <URI>, <FUNCTION>, "}", ";", "/", "-".)
Feb 26, 2014 4:59:40 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: 'http://www.pof.com/css/versioned/main.min.1392865551.css' [1:19023] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
Feb 26, 2014 4:59:40 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.ActiveXObject jsConstructor
WARNING: Automation server can't create object for 'ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash.7'.
Feb 26, 2014 4:59:40 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.StrictErrorReporter runtimeError
SEVERE: runtimeError: message=[Automation server can't create object for 'ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash.7'.] sourceName=[http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js] line=[24] lineSource=[null] lineOffset=[0]
Feb 26, 2014 4:59:40 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.ActiveXObject jsConstructor
WARNING: Automation server can't create object for 'ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash.6'.
Feb 26, 2014 4:59:40 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.StrictErrorReporter runtimeError
SEVERE: runtimeError: message=[Automation server can't create object for 'ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash.6'.] sourceName=[http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js] line=[24] lineSource=[null] lineOffset=[0]
Feb 26, 2014 4:59:40 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.ActiveXObject jsConstructor
WARNING: Automation server can't create object for 'ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash'.
Feb 26, 2014 4:59:40 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.StrictErrorReporter runtimeError
SEVERE: runtimeError: message=[Automation server can't create object for 'ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash'.] sourceName=[http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js] line=[24] lineSource=[null] lineOffset=[0]
Feb 26, 2014 4:59:41 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPasswordInput cannot be cast to com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTextInput
    at DataWebBot.main(DataWebBot.java:28)
```

What is the issue? Am I using the cookies incorrectly? I need them to continue to navigate through other ages of the site, don't I? Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JavaScript file is missing on the server ?

http://www.pof.com/javascript/versioned/1386808612.js

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be pretty clear:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPasswordInput cannot be cast to com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTextInput
```

So change this:

```
final HtmlTextInput passwordField = loginForm.getInputByName("password");
```

Into this:

```
final HtmlPasswordInput passwordField = loginForm.getInputByName("password");
```

That will get you through the exception. As a side note you might face JavaScript issues but that is a different matter.

Comment: Thanks. This was helpful - not sure why I missed it.